# Typescript: parameter of a callback without a specified type next to it breaks code

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

See the code:

```
interface Bar<T> {
    <B_RETURN>(
        a: (aParam: B_RETURN) => any,
        b: (bParam: T) => B_RETURN // B_RETURN is supposed to be inferred from here
        ): any
}

declare const bar: Bar<any>

bar((aParam) => 1, () => 'abc') // OK! `aParam` is `string`
bar((aParam) => 1, (bParam) => 'abc') // `aParam` is `{}`. Why?
bar((aParam) => 1, (bParam: any) => 'abc') // `aParam` is `string`. Again, why?
let arg2 = (bParam) => 'abc' ; bar((aParam ) => 1, arg2) // `aParam` is `string`. Again, why?
```

`aParam` should be `string` in each of the four examples, but for some reason it is `{}` instead of `string` in the second example. Can someone explain why this happens?

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Bar%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CB_RETURN%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20(aParam%3A%20B_RETURN)%20%3D%3E%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20(bParam%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20B_RETURN%20%2F%2F%20B_RETURN%20is%20supposed%20to%20be%20inferred%20from%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3A%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20bar%3A%20Bar%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Abar((aParam)%20%3D%3E%201%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20'abc')%20%2F%2F%20OK!%20%60aParam%60%20is%20%60string%60%0D%0Abar((aParam)%20%3D%3E%201%2C%20(bParam)%20%3D%3E%20'abc')%20%2F%2F%20%60aParam%60%20is%20%60%7B%7D%60.%20Why%3F%0D%0Abar((aParam)%20%3D%3E%201%2C%20(bParam%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20'abc')%20%2F%2F%20%60aParam%60%20is%20%60string%60.%20Again%2C%20why%3F%0D%0Alet%20arg2%20%3D%20(bParam)%20%3D%3E%20'abc'%20%3B%20bar((aParam%20)%20%3D%3E%201%2C%20arg2)%20%2F%2F%20%60aParam%60%20is%20%60string%60.%20Again%2C%20why%3F)

Comment: Fun fact: in case `let arg2 = (bParam) => 'abc'
; bar((aParam) => 1, arg2)` aParam will be also string

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak That's really interesting! Thank you! I will add this to the question and github [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29799).